# Passing scoped template from parent to child component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using **bootstrap-vue.js** to create a table. To make it less redundant through out my project, I am trying to make a wrapper component called **CommonTable.vue** having following code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <b-table
        :class=classname
        :items=items
        :fields=fields
        :current-page=currentPage
        :per-page=perPage
        :show-empty="true"
      >
        <!-- Custom formatted header cells -->
        <template scope="data" :slot="'HEAD_'+headData.fieldName" v-for="headData in tableHeaderData">
          <b-popover triggers="hover" placement="bottom" :content="headData.tooltip">
            {{data.label}}
          </b-popover>
        </template>

        <!-- Custom formatted value cells -->
        <template slot="uptime" scope="item">
          <small>{{item.value}}</small>
        </template>
      </b-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'TableComponent',
    props: ["items", "fields", "classname", "tableHeaderData"],
    data(){
      return {
        currentPage: 1,
        perPage: 35
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

I am then trying to reuse this component everywhere I want to add a table and passing the data and fields information via props like following (**Listing.vue**):

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
              <CommonTable
                    classname='no-margin'
                    :items="items"
                    :fields="fields"
                    :showPagination="showPagination"
                    :tableHeaderData="tableHeaderData"
              >
              </CommonTable>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import CommonTable from '@/components/CommonTable';

  export default {
        name: 'Listing',
        components: {
              'CommonTable': CommonTable
        },
        data() {
              return {
                    tableHeaderData:[
                          {fieldName: "name", tooltip: "User name."},
                          {fieldName: "uptime", tooltip: "Uptime."}
                    ],
                    fields: {
                          name: {label: 'User Name'},
                          uptime: {label: 'Uptime'}
                    },
                    items: [
                          {"name": "Alex", "uptime": "12d 4h 29m 13s"},
                          {"name": "Bob", "uptime": "21d 4h 29m 13s"}
                    ],
                    showPagination: false
              };
        }
  };
</script>
```

**This works fine but is not 100% generic. As visible in CommonTable.vue, I am dynamically generating custom formatted header cells but not doing same for custom formatted value cells.**

**What I want to do is pass the custom formatted header template from the parent component (Listing.vue) and have it compiled into CommonTable.vue at runtime achieving complete dynamicity**

I tried using "slot" concept but failed and I have no other clue to achieve what I desire. Can someone please provide a hint to make that part generic/dynamic as well. Thanks in advance.